# PDFTextStripper: Last letter positioned before first letter

Tags: pdfbox

I am parsing a document using `PDFTextStripper` and in one case `writeString` returns "Transaction details (continued) ". Oddly, that space character after the bracket has a position that is *before* the first character of the String. When I run:

```
@Override
protected void writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException
{
  for (TextPosition position: textPositions)
  {
    System.out.println(position.getUnicode() + ": " + position.getX() + 
      ", " + position.getY());
  }
  super.writeString(text, textPosition);
}
```

I get:

```
T: 53.0, 113.0
r: 60.332, 113.0
a: 65.0, 113.0
n: 71.672, 113.0
s: 79.004, 113.0
a: 85.675995, 113.0
c: 92.34799, 113.0
t: 99.01999, 113.0
i: 103.01599, 113.0
o: 106.35199, 113.0
n: 113.68399, 113.0
 : 121.01599, 113.0
d: 124.35199, 113.0
e: 131.68399, 113.0
t: 138.35599, 113.0
a: 142.35199, 113.0
i: 149.02399, 113.0
l: 152.35999, 113.0
s: 155.69598, 113.0
 : 162.36798, 113.0
(: 165.14798, 113.0
c: 168.47798, 113.0
o: 174.03798, 113.0
n: 180.14798, 113.0
t: 186.25798, 113.0
i: 189.58798, 113.0
n: 192.36798, 113.0
u: 198.47798, 113.0
e: 204.58798, 113.0
d: 210.14798, 113.0
): 216.25798, 113.0
 : 48.0, 118.0
```

Is this normal or should I file a bug report? If this is normal, why does the space belong at the end of the String?

**UPDATE**: I opened the file in Foxit PhantomPDF and I spotted the space character (circled below). It's hard to see but if you zoom closely you'll notice there is a zero-height textbox there.

[image: screenshot]

I'm unsure why PDFBox is appending this character to the end of the String. If anything, it sounds like it should be parsed into a separate line.

Comment: *"Oddly, that space character after the bracket has a position that is before the first character of the String"* - but before the first character on the *next line*! Can you show which data you exactly print?

Comment: @mkl Good catch. See the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the space character is interpreted as a subscript of the line. See the [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4603) I filed for more details. We are supposed to invoke `PDFTextStripper.setSortByPosition(true)` if we want the character to show up at the beginning of the line instead of the end.